# Construct BST from a sorted linked list in O(n) time using iterative method

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

The problem is same as method 2 of this post- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=17063 but using iteration instead of recursion.

Comment: you can always do an iterative recursion using stack

Comment: I solved the problem and below is the solution. Can you think of any other way to do it @marvel308 ?

Comment: Knuth gives an algorithm for this as an exercise in *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 3.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is kind of a hack. I convert the List to the array and then I use three stacks to create a bst. 
nodeStack stores the node I am going to process next, and leftIndexStack and rightIndexStack store the range where this node need to read from the array.

```
 public class Solution {
    public TreeNode sortedListToBST(ListNode head) {
           return sortedArrayToBST(convertListToArray(head));
    }


    public int[] convertListToArray(ListNode head){
        ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList();
        ListNode temp=head;
        while(temp!=null){
            ar.add(temp.val);
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        int[] intArray = new int[ar.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = ar.get(i);
        }
        return intArray;        
    }

    public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums) {

        int len = nums.length;
        if ( len == 0 ) { return null; }

        // 0 as a placeholder
        TreeNode head = new TreeNode(0); 

        Deque<TreeNode> nodeStack       = new LinkedList<TreeNode>() {{ push(head);  }};
        Deque<Integer>  leftIndexStack  = new LinkedList<Integer>()  {{ push(0);     }};
        Deque<Integer>  rightIndexStack = new LinkedList<Integer>()  {{ push(len-1); }};

        while ( !nodeStack.isEmpty() ) {
            TreeNode currNode = nodeStack.pop();
            int left  = leftIndexStack.pop();
            int right = rightIndexStack.pop();
            int mid   = left + (right-left)/2; // avoid overflow
            currNode.val = nums[mid];
            if ( left <= mid-1 ) {
                currNode.left = new TreeNode(0);  
                nodeStack.push(currNode.left);
                leftIndexStack.push(left);
                rightIndexStack.push(mid-1);
            }
            if ( mid+1 <= right ) {
                currNode.right = new TreeNode(0);
                nodeStack.push(currNode.right);
                leftIndexStack.push(mid+1);
                rightIndexStack.push(right);
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: But is it *O(1)*? and if so, why?

Comment: Its O(nlogn). Though stack operations are being used but still processing of the whole array is  being done to construct the tree. The code still finds the middle point and makes it a root and does that recursively for left and right parts. So its still a divide and conquer approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public Node sortedDLLToBSTIterative(){
        int n=countNodes(head);
        Stack<Div> stDiv=new Stack<Div>();
        stDiv.push(new Div(n));
        while(n/2>0){
            stDiv.push(new Div(n/2));
            n=n/2;
        }
        Stack<Node> stRoot=new Stack<Node>();
        Stack<Node> stLeft=new Stack<Node>();
        Stack<Node> stRight=new Stack<Node>();
        Div currDiv;
        int i;
        Node temp=null;
        while(!stDiv.isEmpty()){
            currDiv=stDiv.peek();
            if(currDiv.val/2==0){
                stRoot.push(head);
                stLeft.push(null);
                stRight.push(null);
                head=head.next;
                stDiv.pop();
            }else{
                if(currDiv.left==false && currDiv.right==false){
                    temp=stRoot.pop();
                    temp.prev=stLeft.pop();
                    temp.next=stRight.pop();
                    stLeft.push(temp);
                    stRoot.push(head);
                    head=head.next;
                    currDiv.left=true;
                    i=currDiv.val;
                    while(i/2>0){
                        stDiv.push(new Div(i/2));
                        i=i/2;
                    }
                }else{
                    temp=stRoot.pop();
                    temp.prev=stLeft.pop();
                    temp.next=stRight.pop();
                    stRight.push(temp);
                    stDiv.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        stRoot.peek().prev=stLeft.pop();
        stRoot.peek().next=stRight.pop();
        return stRoot.pop();
    }
public class Div{
    boolean left, right;
    int val;
    public Div(int k){
        val=k;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the input sorted list?

Comment: Here it is 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 where "head" pointer in above program points to 10. Its a double link list.